# Openshift Wildfly 404 not found

Tags: deployment, openshift, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm very new to openshift.

We have created a Wildfly Web Application and deployed it on OpenShift in an non-scalable environment. The openshift deployment shows "Welcome to Wildfly 8" page, and when we query for WEBROOT/faces/index.xhtml, it shows 404 Not Found error.

- The application is deployed to Openshift by Travis CI.
- The travis-CI builds is passing.
- Our local deployment has no problem.
- We setup maven to deploy webapp to ROOT.war in deployment folder.
- We uncompressed the ROOT.war and found index.xhtml

What could be the problem? Not sure which direction to go about this problem.

Comment: it you deploy it as ROOT.war, you should be able to access it on http://ip:port/faces/index.xhtml no need for extra WEBROOT part...

Comment: by WEBROOT I mean our domain, so http://pms-atdefault.rhcloud.com/ I meant when I visit http://pms-atdefault.rhcloud.com/faces/index.xhtml.

Comment: Have you looked in logs for application initialization errors?

Comment: Don't know. Sorry, I don't have access to that instance anymore.